# Rewrite sql server to oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following that is being used for sql server and I need to convert it to an oracle database sql query:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION DateTable (
    @StartDate DATE
    ,@EndDate DATE
    )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

SELECT [FullDateAlternateKey], [CalendarYear], [MonthNumberOfYear]
FROM [AdventureWorksDW].[dbo].[DimDate]
WHERE [FullDateAlternateKey] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

I have not tried anything, and as I am new at creating user defined functions so cannot convert it myself.

Comment: I could transate this for you, but then what happens on the next function you need moved? Oracle SQL Developer has a migration feature that includes a t-sql to plsql translator, so go check that out.

Comment: Generally, you don't. It is much cleaner to join to a table than to try to create a function returning a pipelined collection of objects or a cursor (which are the two solutions you would probably implement if you did translate the function).

Comment: I need to create a function as I need to use this for data analysis purposes,

Comment: @thatjeffsmith your right if your to use that logic then stackoverflow should just close its website as is that not the point of it, to get an answer to a problem another developer is having,

Comment: @Sql-power_bi you haven't prsented a problem. You've prsented homework, please write my code for me.  A proper question would look like, here is my Oracle function returniing a refcursor from the result of my SQL query, but i am getting error PLS-00123. That is a question we can help with, that the site it setup to help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that switching from one database to another might be difficult; all that looks similar and familiar, but yet different and strange.

Here are two options which don't answer your question literally, but illustrate the way you might take to get your job done. I'll use Scott's sample table; function should return data about employees who were hired between dates passed as parameters.

```
SQL> select empno, ename, job, hiredate
  2  from emp
  3  order by hiredate;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK     17.12.1980
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN  20.02.1981
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN  22.02.1981
      7566 JONES      MANAGER   02.04.1981
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER   01.05.1981
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER   09.06.1981
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN  08.09.1981
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN  28.09.1981
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT 17.11.1981
      7900 JAMES      CLERK     03.12.1981
      7902 FORD       ANALYST   03.12.1981
      7934 MILLER     CLERK     23.01.1982
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST   09.12.1982
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK     12.01.1983

14 rows selected.
```

The first one represents a function that returns **ref cursor**.

```
SQL> create or replace function datetable
  2    (par_start_date in date, par_end_date in date)
  3  return sys_refcursor
  4  is
  5    rc sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    open rc for
  8      select empno, ename, job
  9      from emp
 10      where hiredate between par_start_date and par_end_date;
 11
 12    return rc;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> select datetable(date '1981-05-01', date '1981-10-31') from dual;

DATETABLE(DATE'1981-
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN
```

---

Another option returns **custom type**:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row is object
  2    (empno      number,
  3     ename      varchar2(20),
  4     job        varchar2(20));
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab as table of t_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function datetable
  2    (par_start_date in date, par_end_date in date)
  3  return t_tab
  4  is
  5    rc t_tab;
  6  begin
  7      select t_row(empno, ename, job)
  8      bulk collect into rc
  9      from emp
 10      where hiredate between par_start_date and par_end_date;
 11
 12    return rc;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from table(datetable(date '1981-05-01', date '1981-10-31'));

     EMPNO ENAME                JOB
---------- -------------------- --------------------
      7654 MARTIN               SALESMAN
      7698 BLAKE                MANAGER
      7782 CLARK                MANAGER
      7844 TURNER               SALESMAN
```

---

Now, try to rewrite your function, based on info you've just got.